# Asp.Net C# Object Related Ques

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I am new to Asp .net C#. i have question about objects and inheritance.
if i have parent class (Base-Table) that have 2 child classes (Credit-Card-Table ,        Bank-Account-Table) i have fun. in another class that take an object from the base-table class. 
my problem is i want to know if the Base-table is Credit-card or Bank-account ?!

```
class BaseTable
{
    string date;
    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }

    string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

}



class CreditCardTable:BaseTable
{
    string Amount;
    public string amount
    {
        get { return Amount; }
        set { Amount = value; }
    }

    string Type;
    public string type
    {
        get { return Type; }
        set { Type = value; }
    }

}



class BankAccountTable:BaseTable
{
    string Refr;

    public string Ref
    {
        get { return Refr; }
        set { Refr = value; }
    }
    string debit;

    public string Debit
    {
        get { return debit; }
        set { debit = value; }
    }

    string credit;

    public string Credit
    {
        get { return credit; }
        set { credit = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: More often than not something like this is an indication of an error in the design.  Maybe `BaseTable` should be `abstract`?  Maybe the other code needs a child instance and not a base instance?  What specific reason do you have to need to know the type of the instance?

Comment: Why do you need to know what type your `BaseTable` is? Usually this means you've gone wrong in your design. The usual way of approaching this would be to make a virtual/abstract method in `BaseTable` that is overridden in the derived classes to implement the type-specific behaviour. That way, anything using a BaseTable reference can call the virtual method and get different behaviour depending on the actual type of the `BaseTable` reference.

Comment: its a code to create a pdf there is 2 types of pdfs credit card pdf and bank account pdf so in the business i want to check if the obj is credit card or bank account so i can choose which one to create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 options:

1. use `is`, `as` or `GetType()` to explicitly check the type of an instance you have been given, to test it against some known types

   ```
   if(obj is CreditCardTable) {...} else ...
   ```
2. add a `virtual` or `abstract` method to the base-type, and use that *instead* of ever having to worry about which it is (since it will automatically invoke the most derived `override`)

   ```
   obj.SomeMethod();
   ```
3. add a discriminator - perhaps a `virtual` enum property to the `BaseTable` which all derived types return a different value from, and `switch` on that discriminator:

   ```
   switch(obj.Type) { ... }
   ```

Comment: Number two!!!!! Switching on type (effectively options 1&3) suggests a design problem to me.

Comment: @spender depends on the scenario; that would be my preference too, but in some cases separation-of-concerns means that the type itself shouldn't know this "whatever"; for example, if the entity is a POCO, and the "whatever" is "an ORM persisting it", then I would accept the ORM using `.GetType()` and comparing that to the expected types; it isn't the job of the POCO to persist. Likewise with a serializer; so "number one" definitely has some utility